# Deploying Angular2 App, getting unknown non-descriptive error

Tags: angular, angular2-seed

Getting this error in firebug after angular2 app has been deployed : "TypeError: this._nativeError is undefined" in app.js.

*app.js is the javascript that is created from npm run build.prod.aot (and also npm run build.prod).

App runs fine locally, it only seems to give me problems after I've deployed to a standalone web server. I assume I have a minor typo somewhere, but the error looks pretty generic and I can't find anything conclusive as to what might be the cause.

Has anyone seen this issue before? Or have any idea how to narrow down my search in finding it?

Edit: Using this seed project: https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed but comments/answers are suggesting that others have had issue despite using other starters

Comment: getting same issue .

Comment: Are  you using ng2-bootstrap ??   I am getting this issue due to ng2-bootstrap

Comment: @SameerK I haven't added any third party stuff yet and I don't think the seed project uses this (could be wrong), have you found a fix to this? Still might be relevant

Comment: I found that tooltip was one of the module from ng2-bootstrap which was creating this issue, so while importing it i added like `TooltipModule.forRoot(),`. Still have issues with other modules of ng2-bootstrap

Comment: @SameerK Just to double check, your app builds fine locally and in dev right? You only see this when deploying to dist/prod and moving the files to a web server? I think you might be on to something with the imports of certain modules

Comment: I have just created a project with angular-cli and I see it as well.  The pristine generated project works, but as soon as I try to modify the template of the app component, I get this error. I think that I am introducing an error in the template but that the error reporting from Angular is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Around line 1604 in the compiler.umd.js I added a console.log to show me the message.

It is part of the set function of the Object.defineProperty(BaseError.prototype, "message" definition.

The setter is assigning the message to the _nativeError.message, but _nativeError is undefined and thus, THAT was blowing up, hiding the REAL error message.

So, I just put a console.log to spit out the message that was being passed in, and it showed me the actual error I had (a template error).

Therefore, this appears to be a bug in their code.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Might be worth noting that there are other js files (common.umd.min.js, and core.umd.min.js) that you might need to add the console.log to. Mine was not compiler.umd.js and it revealed a DI Error. Not 100% which file did the trick for me, I changed 5-6 of the ones I saw this._nativeError.message=message

Comment: I changed the set in compiler.umd.js (Angular v2.4.1) at line 1607 
My set looks like this:
`set: function (message) { console.log(message); this._nativeError.message = message; },`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks!!! For me it simply worked without uninstalling but just simply installing: npm install zone.js@0.72 - Than node_modules/zone.js/package.json contained _id 0.7.2 rather than 0.7.5 and the error messages became as beautifull as before

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error: "TypeError: this._nativeError is undefined", but I do not use angular-seed.

My stack trace:

```
.set
    assignAll
    ZoneAwareError
    BaseError
    SyntaxError
    CompileMetadataResolver.prototype._getDependenciesMetadata
    CompileMetadataResolver.prototype._getTypeMetadata
...
```

The error was removed after setting: "emitDecoratorMetadata": true in tsconfig.json.

Comment: Do you mean in `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: thanks for the response! Good to know that its not angular seed specific I've updated my question to reflect such.

Comment: @msanford Yes, you are right. Thanks. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and same message. It is a known issue to zone.js version 0.7.5 that the actual error messages are not displayed properly - see also here: [Github Issues on zone.js 0.7.5](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/595)
First I thought, I had version 0.7.2 because the package manager showed me that I had, but I tried and deinstalled with npm, afterwards installed 0.7.2 and now I have a beautiful error message pointing me directly on the nose of the error :) Hope that helps you, too.

Comment: I still get the same vague error message but +1 for the recommendation to update everything - was a little out of date and it is always a good place to start and might help someone else

Comment: it was not a recommendation to update, more to down-date ;)