# this._nativeError is undefined when I bundle my angular 2 application

Tags: angular, gulp, browserify, tsify

I am using `gulp`, `browserify` and `tsify` to bundle my application and I am pointing browserify to the `main.ts` file. That is all I am doing to bundle the app. But when I try to run the `index.html` file which has the bundled js file imported, I get the error: `this._nativeError is undefined` with a blank screen.

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc-e2e",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

My gulp task:

[gulp task](http://pastebin.com/ULpgpd55)

Comment: Which version `zonejs` are you using?

Comment: Zone versions is 0.7.5

Comment: Downgrade to 0.7.4 There is a bug in 7.5 https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/595

Comment: I will check with that. However the application works fine in development mode, which I serve using angular-cli.

Comment: 'Can't resolve all parameters for UserService: (?, ?)' This is what I am getting now and the screen is still blank. what could be causing this?

Comment: This is right error. Maybe you have a circular dependency

Comment: Will this have been caused by of bundling?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing real code

Comment: But it works fine in development mode though.

Comment: While browserify is bundling the application, I am getting this error 'experimental decorators is an experimental option. Please set it in your tsconfig.json file'.

Comment: Could you include your `browserify`/`tsify` configuration, please? If you are seeing that error, `tsify` isn't using/finding your `tsconfig.json`, as you appear to have `experimentalDecorators` enabled.

Comment: @cartant the pastebin link in my description has the browserify options in it. Its in a variable called "defaultOptions".

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `tsify` configuration, you define:

```
defaultOptions = {
  ...
  tsifyOptions: {},
  ...
}
```

but you use:

```
.plugin(tsify, defaultOptions.tsifydefaultOptions)
```

It's unclear as to whether or not it's related to your problem, but if your `tsconfig.json` is not in the same directory as your `package.json` and is not in a parent directory, it won't be found. And as your configuration includes `../node_modules/@types`, it seems likely that it's not.

To let `tsify` know where the `tsconfig.json` is, you can specify the `project` option:

```
.plugin(tsify, { project: './some-directory/tsconfig.json' })
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to suggest with the `../node_modukles/@types`. Can you give me more details on that?

Comment: It's just that if your `tsconfig.json` has that path in it, my guess is that it's not in the same directory as your `package.json` - which is the directory from which `tsify` will start looking for one. There's no problem with that, but `tsify` will need to be told where it is, that's all. The `project` option should be set to the path to your `tsconfig.json` *relative* to your `package.json`.

Comment: Again, this might not solve your problem, but the first thing you need to fix is the `experimentalDecorators` error, as that implies `tsify` cannot find your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: ` import './polyfills.ts';
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' `

This is what I am getting now after I pointed tsify to the tsconfig file.

Comment: I don't think debugging a build in this manner is going to be possible. There are too many unknowns. However, if you are importing `.ts` files from `node_modules`, you should also specify the `global: true` option for `tsify`. You should seriously consider using the `angular-cli` tooling to build a bundle, instead. ...

Comment: ... If you have not used `browserify` or `tsify` before, starting a build with Angular 2 is quite an undertaking, but if you want to persist with it, all I could suggest is that you go through the docs and get things working with a simple project and the `browserify` command line. Then tackle Angular 2 and gulp, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found my solution by putting a console.log inside compiler.umd.js as suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41644735/7434393

> Around line 1604 in the compiler.umd.js I added a console.log to show
>   me the message.
>
> It is part of the set function of the
>   Object.defineProperty(BaseError.prototype, "message" definition.
>
> The setter is assigning the message to the _nativeError.message, but
>   _nativeError is undefined and thus, THAT was blowing up, hiding the REAL error message.
>
> So, I just put a console.log to spit out the message that was being
>   passed in, and it showed me the actual error I had (a template error).
>
> Therefore, this appears to be a bug in their code.